# Flashes screen when im downloading data from firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I have a question if there is any function or possibility that will help me stop flashing the screen when I go from activity to activity in which I have data from firebase displayed in TextView or ImageView?

```
        DatabaseReference uidRef = databaseReference.child(who).child(login);
    uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                    String picprof = task.getResult().child("pimage").getValue(String.class);

                    if(picprof != null){
                        Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
                                .borderColor(Color.WHITE)
                                .borderWidthDp(1)
                                .cornerRadiusDp(100)
                                .oval(true)
                                .build();

                        Picasso.get()
                                .load(picprof)
                                .fit()
                                .transform(transformation)
                                .into(profilepohoto);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "flashing the screen"? Can you show us your code?

Comment: it means refreshing every time when I get back to last Activity

Comment: Are you somehow notifying the entire adapter at each change?

Comment: I don't, Im just getting data from database and setting ImageViews and TextViews. How can I do it?